# PHP's in_array function not working correctly with XML

Tags: php, xml

The code below is being used to retrieve the value of the "store" element from the XML file below and insert the values into an array (the storeArray). I do NOT want duplicate value put into the array (IE I don't want Best Buy inserted twice), so I am using the in_array method
to prevent duplication.

This code does not prevent duplication (IE Best Buy is displayed twice):

```php
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$storeArray = array();

foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) {
    echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
    echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";

    if( !in_array( $Product->store, $storeArray )) {
        $storeArray[] = $Product->store;
    }
}

foreach ($storeArray as $store) {
    echo $store . "<br>";
}
```

But this code does work:

```php
$practiceArray = array('Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3');

if (in_array("Product1", $practiceArray)) {
    echo "Is in array";}
else {  
    echo "NOT in array";
}
```

Any advice?

Here is the XML file:

```xml
<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name> Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Lap top</name>
<price>599.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this

```
if( !in_array( (string)$Product->store, $storeArray )) {
    $storeArray[] = (string)$Product->store;
}
```

because `$Product->store` is not a string: it's a `SimpleXMLElement` object. So you should cast it as string before its manipulation.

Comment: What variable type could it be cast initially besides string?

Comment: @SetSailMedia you can cast any type (array) (bool) (string)... the problem is if the result is what you expected. :)

Comment: How does `in_array()` scores when `$storeArray[]` grows larger?